# Better way to loop in parallel

Tags: java, java-8

If I want to parallelize this code:

```
try {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
        new File(String.valueOf(i)).createNewFile();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

then I rewrite it to:

```
ArrayList<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 10000; i++) {
    fileNames.add(String.valueOf(i));
}
fileNames.parallelStream().forEach(i -> new File(i).createNewFile());
```

But isn't there a better (simpler) way for that?

Comment: There are better ways than that to "*parallelize this code*". What exactly are you trying to improve? Performance/Readability/Parallelisation?

Comment: File system operations are still sequential. So you will not get any performance boost with such parallelization.

Comment: What I want to know is Mushif's answer (`IntStream.range(0, 10000).parallel().forEach(...`) but every comments and answers helps me. Thank you!

Comment: `.forEach()` must not mutate the state, your code is degenerate in the first place. You write iterative logic using streams which are designed for functional programming, this is an antipattern.

Comment: @blackeyedcenter I am glad that my answer helped you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `IntStream` in `parallel()`:

```
IntStream.range(0, 10000).parallel().forEach(i -> {
    try {
        new File(String.valueOf(i)).createNewFile();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
});
```

But it won't be much efficient because of the disk operations.

Answer (score 3):

A distinct non-answer:

> If I want to parallelize this code:

Then you would (most likely) need to turn to a completely different hardware/software stack to gain anything from doing so.

You see, unless we are talking about some sort of "remote" file system, that can be (and actually **is**) reached via multiple "paths", and that actually resembles multiple IO devices ... your attempt of optimisation is **pointless**.

It only makes sense to parallelize activities that include a lot of **waiting** for **different** things. But in your case, your code talks to **one** operating system, using **one** file system. Most likely, your idea is even slowing down things.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not accept this answer but voted +1 as it is very helpful.

Comment: @blackeyedcenter Very much appreciated. But it would be fair to upvote the other answer as well ;-)

Answer (score 0):

just to have another possibility..

```
fileNames.parallelStream().map(Path::Files.createFile).collect(Collectors.toList());
fileNames.stream().map(path -> Files.createFile(path)).collect(...
```

between returns a list with objects Path inside.